# How to print the local system time using log4cplus?

Tags: logging, log4cplus

While choosing `PatternLayout` if I use `%d{%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S}`, it will show the current date and time. The time is according to the `UTC` format.

My requirement is to display the time accoring to local system time.

**Update:**

In `timehelper.h` there is one method `Time::localtime` will it show the time according to the local system time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [PatternLayout class documentation](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PatternLayout.html). The detailed description has a table enumerating all the formats. There you should be able to see that UTC is printed by `%d` and that local time is printed by `%D`.

Just change the initial `%d` to `%D`.

Comment: Thank you Wilx. I have gone through the PatternLayout class, but possibly I missed that point. It resolved my issue.